# itgenobr001: Client not found. on Data Access Point with Exact Online Belgium

Tags: exact-online, invantive-query-tool, invantive-dap

We have just gone live with https://ecotaksen.be. The queries and updates on Exact were running fine, but after installing the production license an error `itgenobr001: Client not found.` occurs.

My data container specification is:

```
<database order="1" 
   creationDate="2016-04-13T09:11:03.3584276+02:00"
   provider="ExactOnlineAll" 
   connectionString="apiUrl=https://start.exactonline.be" 
/>
```

The connection to Exact Online using Query Tool with the same credentials and connection string is working fine.

How can I solve the `itgenobr001` error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact it was quite simple to solve: the "Client" referred to is the application. I needed to add the client ID of Exact Online app to my connection string, since Data Access Point requires a client ID when using a production license.

Resulting data container specification:

```
<database order="1" creationDate="2016-04-13T09:11:03.3584276+02:00" provider="ExactOnlineAll"
 connectionString="apiUrl=https://start.exactonline.be;api-client-id=MYID" />
```

After that, I got a `itgenobr001: Invalid authorization request.`, and that one required addition of the redirect url as specified in the My Apps page in Exact Online:

```
<database order="1" creationDate="2016-04-13T09:11:03.3584276+02:00" provider="ExactOnlineAll" 
connectionString="apiUrl=https://start.exactonline.be;api-client-id=MYID;apiredirecturl=https://ecotaksen.be" />
```