# itgenuty427 on connec to Exact Online: Please configure api-client-id in your connection string

Tags: exact-online, invantive-data-hub

After re-installing the server with Windows and Invantive Data Hub with MySQL drivers, I get the following error when I try to connect to Exact Online (nl):

```
Waarschuwing itgenuty427: Een verbinding met de database 'Exact Online\Exact Online (nl)' kon niet worden opgebouwd als gebruiker 'richardvos'.
The application 'InvantiveDataHub' can only be used in production mode with your own client ID.
```

Please configure api-client-id in your connection string to configure the client ID.

Before the re-install it worked fine. I can connect to MySQL from within Invantive Data Hub but not to Exact Online.

How can I configure the api-client-id?

Answer (score 0):

See question [on Data Access Point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42647606/itgenobr001-client-not-found-on-data-access-point-with-exact-online-belgium).

You need to configure a client ID and redirect URL in your settings.xml file:

```
<database order="1" creationDate="2016-04-13T09:11:03.3584276+02:00" provider="ExactOnlineAll" 
  connectionString="apiUrl=https://start.exactonline.be;api-client-id=MYID;apiredirecturl=https://ecotaksen.be" />
```

It is best to store these settings not in settings.xml, but in a settings-my-file.xml next to it which is automatically merged into the main settings.xml. And of course keep a copy somewhere on another device :-)